# delete users in a membership provider database

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2012, membership-provider

I am using Asp.net's Membership Provider with Sql Server 2012. My web application works fine and connects without issue. I have written a desktop application that allows our customers to modify the current users.

I have most of the application working straight through the database using linq except the delete user.

I cannot add the membership provider to my application since I do not have an app.config.

I have been using linq to change the passwords and user info but deleting a user has been a little bit of an issue since, well, I don't know what all I need to delete.

I need a way to delete the user either with a stored procedure or using linq.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Why use linq and not simply the membership layer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5xxz7y3a(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The delete user is the only thing I need to do and I want to avoid using the app.config since my application has not needed it up to this point.

Comment: So where is your connection string stored?